# Put together all possible combinations of a set of functions, variables, and operators

Tags: permutation

Using a set of functions, variables, and operators, I'm trying to assemble all of the possible combinations starting with the shortest combination and ending with the longest combination. For example, given the functions sin, cos, tan; the variables x, y, z; and basic operators +, -, *, /, ^, generate output starting with x, y, z. Next, the second set with valid syntax being sin(x), cos(x), tan(x), sin(y), cos(y), tan(y), sin(z), cos(z), tan(z).

Bonus Points if it can then integrate from 0 to 1,2,3 after generating the equations.

Please forgive my prototype since I'm new to Mathematica

```
ClearAll[allCompositions]
allCompositions[a_] := Through@(Permutations@*Composition)[##]@a &;

f1[x_] := sin (x);
f2[x_] := cos (x);
f3[x_] := tan(x);

combos1 = allCompositions[x][f1, f2, f3] // FullSimplify

f[x_] := {combos1}
Integrate[f[x], {x, 0, 1}]
```

Comment: Welcome to MathematicaStackExchange! Built-in functions are capitalized, and you should use square brackets, so `Sin[x]` instead of `sin(x)`. Also, it is not completely clear what you mean by _all possible combinations_. There are infinitely many of them, for example: $x+\sin(x) + x\cos(x) + \sin(\tan(x^x))$. Perhaps it would be helpful to clarify what exactly is your _final goal_ in this task, or what do you want this functions to use for (because there might be some better approaches to your problem then brute-force enumeration).

Comment: Are you only allowed to use each object once per expression?

Comment: @Domen I know these combinations can go on infinitely, so the goal would be to create all possible combinations using from 1 to, lets say 5 functions/variables/operators. I literally want to brute force this to generate all possible combinations up to a certain point.

Comment: @Marius Ladegård Meyer I'd like to use each object one time to start with, but might eventually try using each object several times. It really depends on what my computer can handle.